# interfaz grafica conlibreria qt y lenguaje c++

Tags: c++, qt

He desarrollando una interfaz grafica, pero el problea es el manejo de los puntero.El codigo del programa es el siguiente

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QScrollBar>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QProgressBar>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;





class LineArea: public QWidget{
public:
    QTextEdit **area_name;
    int num_elements=0;
    QTextEdit **get_area_name();
    LineArea(QWidget *parent,int num_elements);
    void set_area_name(QTextEdit *area_name_p[]);
};

class Label: public QWidget{
public:
    QLabel **lbl_name;
    int num_elements;
    QLabel **get_lbl_name();
    Label(QWidget *parent,int num_elements);
    void set_lbl_name(QLabel *lbl_name_p[]);
};


class CheckBox: public QWidget{
    public:
        QCheckBox **get_chk_name();
        QCheckBox **check_name;
        CheckBox(QWidget *parent,int num_elements);
        void set_chk_name(QCheckBox *chk_name_p[]);
};

class Progressbar: public QWidget{
public:
    QProgressBar **get_pgsb_name();
    QProgressBar **prsb_name;
    Progressbar(QWidget *parent,int num_elements);
    void set_pgsh_name(QProgressBar *pgsb_name_p[]);
};


class Lineedit: public QWidget{
public:
    QLineEdit **get_edit_name();
    QLineEdit **edit_name;
    Lineedit(QLineEdit *parent,int num_elements);
    void set_edit_name(QLineEdit *line_name_p[]);
};


class Pushbutton: public QWidget{
public:
    QPushButton **get_psh_name();
    QPushButton **psh_name;
    Pushbutton(QWidget *parent,int num_elements);
    void set_psh_name(QPushButton *psh_name_p[]);
};

class Spinbox : public QWidget{
public:
    QSpinBox **get_spn_name();
    QSpinBox **spn_name;
    Spinbox(QWidget *parent ,int num_elements);
    void set_spn_name(QSpinBox *spn_name_p[]);
};

class LineEdit  : public QWidget{
public :
    QLineEdit **get_edit_name();
    QLineEdit **edit_name;
    LineEdit(QWidget *parent,int num_elements);
    void set_edit_name(QLineEdit *edit_name_p[]);
};


struct increments{
  int _pos_x=0;
  int _pos_y=0;
  int _pos_z=0;
  int _width_x=0;
  int _height_y=0;
  int _anchor_z=0;
};



int _volts_1=0;
struct increments  *t_incs;
LineArea::LineArea(QWidget *parent,int num_elements):QWidget(parent){
    t_incs=(struct increments *)malloc(sizeof(struct increments *));
    LineArea::num_elements=num_elements;
    area_name=(QTextEdit **)malloc(sizeof(QTextEdit*)*LineArea::num_elements);
    if (area_name==NULL){
        printf("LO SIENTO NO FUE POSIBLE ASIGNAR MEMORIA A LOS ELEMENTOS  TEXTAREA");
    }
    t_incs->_pos_z=0;
    t_incs->_anchor_z=50;
    t_incs->_width_x=300;
    t_incs->_height_y=100;
    QLinearGradient *lineal=new QLinearGradient(QPointF(100, 100), QPointF(300, 300));
    lineal->setColorAt(0, Qt::black);
    lineal->setColorAt(0.5, Qt::cyan);
    lineal->setColorAt(1, Qt::black);
    QBrush  *brush = new QBrush(*lineal);
    QPalette *paleta=new QPalette();

    for (_volts_1=0;_volts_1<LineArea::num_elements;_volts_1++){
        area_name[_volts_1]=(QTextEdit*)malloc(sizeof(QTextEdit));
        area_name[_volts_1]=new QTextEdit(parent);
        area_name[_volts_1]->setReadOnly(false);
        area_name[_volts_1]->setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit::WidgetWidth);
        area_name[_volts_1]->setFixedSize(t_incs->_width_x,t_incs->_height_y);
        area_name[_volts_1]->move(t_incs->_pos_x,t_incs->_pos_y);
        area_name[_volts_1]->setFont(QFont("Arial Narrow",10));
        paleta->setBrush(QPalette::Base,*brush);
        area_name[_volts_1]->setPalette(*paleta);
        t_incs->_pos_x=t_incs->_pos_x+t_incs->_anchor_z+t_incs->_width_x;
    }
    set_area_name(area_name);
}

Label::Label(QWidget *parent,int num_elements):QWidget(parent){
    t_incs=(struct increments *)malloc(sizeof(struct increments *));
    Label::num_elements=num_elements;
    lbl_name=(QLabel **)malloc(sizeof(QLabel*)*Label::num_elements);
    if (lbl_name==NULL){
        printf("LO SIENTO NO FUE POSIBLE ASIGNAR MEMORIA A LOS ELEMENTOS  LABEL");
    }
    t_incs->_pos_z=0;
    t_incs->_anchor_z=50;
    t_incs->_width_x=500;
    t_incs->_height_y=100;
    QLinearGradient *lineal=new QLinearGradient(QPointF(100, 100), QPointF(300, 300));
    lineal->setColorAt(0, Qt::black);
    lineal->setColorAt(0.5, Qt::cyan);
    lineal->setColorAt(1, Qt::black);
    QLinearGradient  *lineal2=new QLinearGradient(QPointF(100,100),QPointF(150,150));
    lineal2->setColorAt(0,Qt::white);
    lineal2->setColorAt(0.5,Qt::green);
    lineal2->setColorAt(1,Qt::white);
    QBrush  *brush = new QBrush(*lineal);
    QBrush  *brush2 =new QBrush(*lineal2);
    QString albl[]={"Direccion ip victima","Puerto de red victima","Porcentaje del ataque","Tam del paquete","Numero de paquete","Info"};
    QPalette *paleta2=new QPalette(QPalette::WindowText,Qt::black);
    for (_volts_1=0;_volts_1<Label::num_elements;_volts_1++){
        lbl_name[_volts_1]=(QLabel*)malloc(sizeof(QLabel));
        lbl_name[_volts_1]=new QLabel(parent);
        lbl_name[_volts_1]->setText(albl[_volts_1]);
        lbl_name[_volts_1]->setFixedSize(t_incs->_width_x,t_incs->_height_y);
        lbl_name[_volts_1]->move(t_incs->_pos_x,t_incs->_pos_y);
        lbl_name[_volts_1]->setFont(QFont("Arial Narrow",10));//Definimos la fuente y el tam de la fuenete para un
        paleta2->setBrush(QPalette::Base,*brush);
        QPainter *painter=new QPainter();
        painter->drawRoundedRect(0,5,lbl_name[_volts_1]->width()-5, lbl_name[_volts_1]->height()-7,3,3);
        painter->setBrush(*brush2);
        lbl_name[_volts_1]->setPalette(*paleta2);
        lbl_name[_volts_1]->setAutoFillBackground(true);
        QPalette paleta=lbl_name[_volts_1]->palette();
        paleta.setColor(lbl_name[_volts_1]->foregroundRole(),Qt::cyan);
        lbl_name[_volts_1]->setPalette(paleta);
        t_incs->_pos_x=t_incs->_pos_x+t_incs->_anchor_z+t_incs->_width_x;
    }
    set_lbl_name(lbl_name);
}

char* convert_array_string(QString array[],int num_elements,int size_string){
     int _y=0,_w=0;
     char temp_str[size_string];
     for (int _x=0;_x<num_elements;_x++){
         char text_temp[array[_x].length()];
         for (int _z=0;_z<array[_x].length();_z++){
            if (array[_x].data()[_z].toLatin1()!=','){
                text_temp[_y]=array[_x].data()[_z].toLatin1();
                temp_str[_w]=array[_x].data()[_z].toLatin1();
                printf("%c",text_temp[_y]);
                _y++;
            }else
            {
                temp_str[_w]='\n';
                text_temp[_y]='\n';
            }
            _w++;
        }
     }
     return temp_str;
}

int get_size_array_qstring(int num_elements,QString array[]){
    int tam_temp=0;
    int inc_tam=0;
    for (int _x=0;_x<num_elements;_x++){
        inc_tam=inc_tam+ array[_x].length();
    }
    tam_temp=inc_tam;
    return tam_temp;
}

CheckBox::CheckBox(QWidget *parent,int num_elements): QWidget(parent){
    t_incs=(struct increments *)malloc(sizeof(struct increments *));
    check_name=(QCheckBox **)malloc(sizeof(QCheckBox* )*num_elements);
    if (check_name==NULL){
        printf("LO SIENTO NO FUE POSIBLE ASIGNAR MEMORIA A LOS ELEMENTOS  LABEL");
    }
    t_incs->_pos_z=0;
    t_incs->_anchor_z=50;
    t_incs->_width_x=300;
    t_incs->_height_y=100;
    QLinearGradient *lineal=new QLinearGradient(QPointF(100, 100), QPointF(300, 300));
    QColor *color=new QColor(0,153,25,150);
    QColor *color2=new QColor(144, 238,144,150);
    lineal->setColorAt(0,*color);
    lineal->setColorAt(1,*color2);
    QPalette *background_palette=new QPalette(QPalette::WindowText,Qt::black);
    QBrush  *brush = new QBrush (*lineal);
    QString achk_text[]={"Ataque con paquetes ACK,","Ataque con paquetes SYN(Mejor conocido como SYN flood),","Ataque con paquetes SYN/ACK,","Ataque con paquetes UDP(Mejor conocido como UDP flood),","Ataque con paquetes ICMP(Mejor conocido como ICMP flood,"};
    QString achk_name[]={"Ataque_ACK,","Ataque_SYN,","Ataque_SYN/ACK","Ataque_UDP","Ataque_ICMP,"};
    char *chk_text;
    int size_array_qstring=get_size_array_qstring(num_elements,achk_name);
    chk_text=convert_array_string(achk_name,num_elements,size_array_qstring);

    int _increment=0;
    for (int _x=0;_x<num_elements;_x++){
                check_name[_increment]=(QCheckBox *)malloc(sizeof(QCheckBox*));
                check_name[_increment]=new QCheckBox(achk_text[_increment],parent);
                check_name[_increment]->setAutoFillBackground(true);
                background_palette->setBrush(QPalette::Button,*brush);
                check_name[_increment]->setObjectName(achk_name[_increment]);
                check_name[_increment]->setPalette(*background_palette);
                t_incs->_pos_x=t_incs->_pos_x+t_incs->_anchor_z+t_incs->_width_x;
    }
    set_chk_name(check_name);
}

Progressbar::Progressbar(QWidget *parent,int num_elements): QWidget(parent){
    t_incs=(struct increments *)malloc(sizeof(struct increments *));
    prsb_name=(QProgressBar **)malloc(sizeof(QProgressBar* )*num_elements);
    if (prsb_name==NULL){
        printf("LO SIENTO NO FUE POSIBLE ASIGNAR MEMORIA A LOS ELEMENTOS  LABEL");
    }
    t_incs->_pos_z=0;
    t_incs->_anchor_z=50;
    t_incs->_width_x=300;
    t_incs->_height_y=100;
    QLinearGradient *lineal=new QLinearGradient(QPointF(100, 100), QPointF(300, 300));
    QColor *color=new QColor(0,153,25,150);
    QColor *color2=new QColor(144, 238,144,150);
    lineal->setColorAt(0,*color);
    lineal->setColorAt(1,*color2);
    QPalette *background_palette=new QPalette(QPalette::WindowText,Qt::black);
    QBrush  *brush = new QBrush(*lineal);
    int _increment=0;
    QString pgrs_name[]={"PROGRESO_DOS"};
    for (int _x=0;_x<num_elements;_x++){
                prsb_name[_increment]=(QProgressBar *)malloc(sizeof(QProgressBar*));
                prsb_name[_increment]=new QProgressBar(parent);
                prsb_name[_increment]->setTextDirection(QProgressBar::TopToBottom);
                prsb_name[_increment]->setAutoFillBackground(true);
                background_palette->setBrush(QPalette::Button,*brush);
                prsb_name[_increment]->setObjectName(pgrs_name[_increment]);
                prsb_name[_increment]->setPalette(*background_palette);
                t_incs->_pos_x=t_incs->_pos_x+t_incs->_anchor_z+t_incs->_width_x;
    }
    set_pgsh_name(prsb_name);
}


Pushbutton::Pushbutton(QWidget *parent,int num_elements): QWidget(parent){
    t_incs=(struct increments *)malloc(sizeof(struct increments *));
    psh_name=(QPushButton **)malloc(sizeof(QPushButton* )*num_elements);
    if (psh_name==NULL){
        printf("LO SIENTO NO FUE POSIBLE ASIGNAR MEMORIA A LOS ELEMENTOS  LABEL");
    }
    t_incs->_pos_z=0;
    t_incs->_anchor_z=50;
    t_incs->_width_x=300;
    t_incs->_height_y=100;
    QLinearGradient *lineal=new QLinearGradient(QPointF(100, 100), QPointF(300, 300));
    QColor *color=new QColor(0,153,25,150);
    QColor *color2=new QColor(144, 238,144,150);
    lineal->setColorAt(0,*color);
    lineal->setColorAt(1,*color2);
    QString achk_name[]={"OOBTENR DIRECCION IP DE HOST","OBTENER MAC DE HOST ","OBTENER IP DEL ROUTER ","OBTENER MAC DEL ROUTER ","OBTENER INTERFAZ DE RED DE HOST","IINICIAR DOS KILLER"};
    QPalette *background_palette=new QPalette(QPalette::WindowText,Qt::black);
    QBrush  *brush = new QBrush(*lineal);
    int _increment=0;
    for (int _x=0;_x<num_elements;_x++){
               psh_name[_increment]=(QPushButton *)malloc(sizeof(QPushButton*));
                psh_name[_increment]=new QPushButton(parent);
                psh_name[_increment]->setAutoFillBackground(true);
                background_palette->setBrush(QPalette::Button,*brush);
                psh_name[_increment]->setObjectName(achk_name[_increment]);
                psh_name[_increment]->setPalette(*background_palette);
                t_incs->_pos_x=t_incs->_pos_x+t_incs->_anchor_z+t_incs->_width_x;
    }
    set_psh_name(psh_name);
}

Spinbox::Spinbox(QWidget *parent,int num_elements): QWidget(parent){
    t_incs=(struct increments *)malloc(sizeof(struct increments*));
    spn_name=(QSpinBox **)malloc(sizeof(QSpinBox*)*num_elements);
    if (spn_name==NULL){
        printf("LO SIENTO NO FUE POSIBLE ASIGNAR MEMORIA A LOS ELEMENTOS  LABEL");
    }
    t_incs->_pos_z=0;
    t_incs->_anchor_z=50;
    t_incs->_width_x=300;
    t_incs->_height_y=100;
    QLinearGradient *lineal=new QLinearGradient(QPointF(100, 100), QPointF(300, 300));
    QColor *color=new QColor(0,153,25,150);
    QColor *color2=new QColor(144, 238,144,150);
    lineal->setColorAt(0,*color);
    lineal->setColorAt(1,*color2);
    QString aspn_name[]={"TAM PAQUETE","NUMERO DE PAQUETES"};
    QPalette *background_palette=new QPalette(QPalette::WindowText,Qt::black);
    QBrush  *brush = new QBrush(*lineal);
    int _increment=0;
    int maximiun[]={10000,50000};
    int miniun[]={1000,10000};
    for (int _x=0;_x<num_elements;_x++){
                spn_name[_increment]=(QSpinBox *)malloc(sizeof(QSpinBox*));
                spn_name[_increment]=new QSpinBox(parent);
                spn_name[_increment]->setRange(miniun[_x], maximiun[_x]);
                spn_name[_increment]->setAutoFillBackground(true);
                background_palette->setBrush(QPalette::Button,*brush);
                spn_name[_increment]->setObjectName(aspn_name[_increment]);
                spn_name[_increment]->setPalette(*background_palette);
                t_incs->_pos_x=t_incs->_pos_x+t_incs->_anchor_z+t_incs->_width_x;
    }
    set_spn_name(spn_name);
}


LineEdit::LineEdit(QWidget *parent,int num_elements): QWidget(parent){
    t_incs=(struct increments *)malloc(sizeof(struct increments*));
    edit_name=(QLineEdit **)malloc(sizeof(QLineEdit* )*num_elements);
    if (edit_name==NULL){
        printf("LO SIENTO NO FUE POSIBLE ASIGNAR MEMORIA A LOS ELEMENTOS  LABEL");
    }
    t_incs->_pos_z=0;
    t_incs->_anchor_z=50;
    t_incs->_width_x=300;
    t_incs->_height_y=100;
    QLinearGradient *lineal=new QLinearGradient(QPointF(100, 100), QPointF(300, 300));
    QColor *color=new QColor(0,153,25,150);
    QColor *color2=new QColor(144, 238,144,150);
    lineal->setColorAt(0,*color);
    lineal->setColorAt(1,*color2);
    QString aedit_name[]={"EDIT_DIRECCION_IP","EDIT_PUERTO_IP"};
    QPalette *background_palette=new QPalette(QPalette::WindowText,Qt::black);
    QBrush  *brush = new QBrush(*lineal);
    int _increment=0;
    for (int _x=0;_x<num_elements;_x++){
                edit_name[_increment]=(QLineEdit *)malloc(sizeof(QLineEdit*));
                edit_name[_increment]=new QLineEdit(parent);
                edit_name[_increment]->setAutoFillBackground(true);
                background_palette->setBrush(QPalette::Button,*brush);
                edit_name[_increment]->setObjectName(aedit_name[_increment]);
                edit_name[_increment]->setPalette(*background_palette);
                t_incs->_pos_x=t_incs->_pos_x+t_incs->_anchor_z+t_incs->_width_x;
    }
    set_edit_name(edit_name);
}


void Label::set_lbl_name(QLabel *lbl_name_p[]){
    Label::lbl_name=lbl_name_p;
}

void LineArea::set_area_name(QTextEdit *area_name_p[]){
    LineArea::area_name=area_name_p;
}
void CheckBox::set_chk_name(QCheckBox *chk_name[]){
    CheckBox::check_name=chk_name;
}
void Progressbar::set_pgsh_name(QProgressBar *prsb_name[]){
    Progressbar::prsb_name=prsb_name;
}
void Spinbox::set_spn_name(QSpinBox *spn_name[]){
Spinbox::spn_name=spn_name;
}

void Pushbutton::set_psh_name(QPushButton *psh_name[]){
Pushbutton::psh_name=psh_name;
}

void LineEdit::set_edit_name(QLineEdit *edit_name[]){
    LineEdit::edit_name=edit_name;
}
QLabel **Label::get_lbl_name(){
return Label::lbl_name;
}

QTextEdit** LineArea::get_area_name(){
    return LineArea::area_name;
}

QCheckBox **CheckBox::get_chk_name(){
    return CheckBox::check_name;
}
QProgressBar **Progressbar::get_pgsb_name(){
return Progressbar::prsb_name;
}

QSpinBox  **Spinbox::get_spn_name(){
    return Spinbox::spn_name;
}
QPushButton **Pushbutton::get_psh_name(){
    return Pushbutton::psh_name;
}
QLineEdit **LineEdit::get_edit_name(){
    return LineEdit::edit_name;
}

int  interface_started(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QTextStream out(stdout);
    printf("Procesando interfaz grafica...");
    QApplication  app(argc,argv);
    QWidget window;

    printf("Procesando labels...");
    Label   *lbl_x=new Label(&window,6);
    printf("\n Procesando checkboxes...");
    //getchar();
    CheckBox *chk_x=new CheckBox(&window,5);
        printf("\n Procesando spinboxes...");
    //getchar();
    Spinbox *spn_x =new Spinbox(&window,2);
        printf("\n Procesando linedits...");
    //getchar();
    LineEdit *edit_x=new LineEdit(&window,2);
        printf("\n Procesando lineareas...");

    LineArea *area_x=new LineArea(&window,1);
        printf("\n Procesando progressbars...");

    Progressbar *prgs_x=new Progressbar(&window,1);
        printf("\n Procesando pushbuttons...");


    Pushbutton *psh_x= new Pushbutton(&window,6);

    QVBoxLayout  *vbox_panel_1=new QVBoxLayout();
    vbox_panel_1->addWidget(lbl_x->get_lbl_name()[0],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);

    vbox_panel_1->addWidget(edit_x->get_edit_name()[0],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);

    vbox_panel_1->addWidget(lbl_x->get_lbl_name()[1],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    //label ing
    vbox_panel_1->addWidget(edit_x->get_edit_name()[1],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);

    //lineedit ingresar puerto de red
    printf("Panel 1 procesado");
    getchar();
    QVBoxLayout  *vbox_panel_2=new QVBoxLayout();
    //Ataque  SYN
    vbox_panel_2->addWidget(chk_x->get_chk_name()[0],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    //Ataque  ACK
    vbox_panel_2->addWidget(chk_x->get_chk_name()[1],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    //Ataque SYN /ACK
    vbox_panel_2->addWidget(chk_x->get_chk_name()[2],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    //Ataque ICMP
    vbox_panel_2->addWidget(chk_x->get_chk_name()[3],0,Qt::AlignLeft |  Qt::AlignTop);
    //Ataque  UDP
    vbox_panel_2->addWidget(chk_x->get_chk_name()[4],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
printf("Panel 2 generado");
    QVBoxLayout *vbox_panel_3=new QVBoxLayout();
    //label  numero de paquetes
    vbox_panel_3->addWidget(lbl_x->get_lbl_name()[2],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    //spin elegir numero de paquete  10000 - 50000
    vbox_panel_3->addWidget(spn_x->get_spn_name()[0],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    //label tam del paquete
    vbox_panel_3->addWidget(lbl_x->get_lbl_name()[3],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    //spin  elegir  tam del paquete 1000-10000
    vbox_panel_3->addWidget(spn_x->get_spn_name()[1],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    QVBoxLayout *vbox_panel_4=new QVBoxLayout();
    //obtener  direccion ip de su maquina
    vbox_panel_4->addWidget(psh_x->get_psh_name()[0],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    //obtener mc de su maquina
    vbox_panel_4->addWidget(psh_x->get_psh_name()[1],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    //obtener direccion ip del router
    vbox_panel_4->addWidget(psh_x->get_psh_name()[2],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    //obtener mac del router
    vbox_panel_4->addWidget(psh_x->get_psh_name()[3],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    //obtenr interfaz de red
    vbox_panel_4->addWidget(psh_x->get_psh_name()[4],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);

    QHBoxLayout  *hbox_panel_1=new QHBoxLayout();
    hbox_panel_1->addWidget(lbl_x->get_lbl_name()[0],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop );
    hbox_panel_1->addWidget(prgs_x->get_pgsb_name()[0],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    QHBoxLayout  *hbox_panel_2=new QHBoxLayout();
    hbox_panel_2->addWidget(psh_x->get_psh_name()[5],0,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);

    QVBoxLayout *vbox_second_izq=new QVBoxLayout();
    QVBoxLayout *vbox_second_der=new QVBoxLayout();
    vbox_second_izq->addItem(vbox_panel_1);
    vbox_second_izq->addItem(vbox_panel_2);
    vbox_second_izq->addItem(hbox_panel_1);
    vbox_second_der->addItem(vbox_panel_3);
    vbox_second_der->addItem(vbox_panel_4);
    vbox_second_der->addItem(hbox_panel_2);

    QScrollArea *scroll_izq=new QScrollArea(&window);
    QScrollBar  *horizontal_scroll=new QScrollBar(Qt::Horizontal,scroll_izq);
    QScrollBar  *vertical_scroll=new QScrollBar(Qt::Vertical,scroll_izq);
    scroll_izq->setHorizontalScrollBar(horizontal_scroll);
    scroll_izq->setVerticalScrollBar(vertical_scroll);
    scroll_izq->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    scroll_izq->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    scroll_izq->setWidgetResizable(true);
    scroll_izq->setLayout(vbox_second_izq);
    scroll_izq->setGeometry(0,0,1500,700);

    QScrollArea  *scroll_der=new QScrollArea(&window);
    QScrollBar  *horizontal_scroll_der=new QScrollBar(Qt::Horizontal,scroll_der);
    QScrollBar  *vertical_scroll_der=new QScrollBar(Qt::Vertical,scroll_der);
    scroll_der->setHorizontalScrollBar(horizontal_scroll_der);
    scroll_der->setVerticalScrollBar(vertical_scroll_der);
    scroll_der->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    scroll_der->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    scroll_der->setWidgetResizable(true);
    scroll_der->setGeometry(0,0,1500,700);
    scroll_der->setLayout(vbox_second_der);

    QHBoxLayout *main_layout=new QHBoxLayout();
    main_layout->addItem(vbox_second_izq);
    main_layout->addItem(vbox_second_der);


    printf("\n INTERFACE NEON");
    window.setLayout(main_layout);
    window.setGeometry(100,100,1500,700);
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
return   interface_started(argc,argv);
}
```

Para compilarlo con g++ se requiere que tengan instalador la libreria qt5  ademas del compilador  de c++  el comandos para correrlo en linux es el siguientes:

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs Qt5Widgets , Qt5Core ,Qt5Gui) prueba.cpp -o probe
```

El problema que me da es violación de segmento.

Comment: Hola @aldairMartinez, tu pregunta tiene codigo demaciado largo, en la proxima te recomiendo que vea la porcion de codigo que te lanza el error y lo pongas en la pregunta(Claro si al llamar a function() te da el error debes enseñar como la llamaste y como es la funcion). Te ayudaria pero no me familieriso con la biblioteca qt

Comment: para ver donde accedes a una memoria invalida puedes usar gdb(depurador c++), cuando lo ejecuta con gdb el detiene el programa cuando intenta acceder a una posicion de la memoria invalida y te dice, claro debes incluir la opcion -g al momento de compilarlo con g++

Comment: solo quiero que me ayuden a resolverlo  hermano me ayudas  ? te loa gradecria mi ocn que  aparezca la interfaz sea comos ea  cambiale el codigo si queires  pero con que funcione la interfaz yo estare agradecido con puntos contigo

Comment: Entiendo. Primero para resolver el error debemos localizarlo. Un depurador es una muy buena opcion para eso.

Comment: ¿Como te fue? Podemos seguir hablando aqui: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: Por favor, consulta **urgentemente** [El Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) del sitio, en concreto lo que es un [mcve] y también [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Limita tu código a lo mínimo imprescindible, muestra los datos relevantes (incluidos **los mensajes de error**) y pon un título acorde al problema. Un saludo.

Comment: Verifica estos enclaces para ver si satisfacen tu problema: 1. [Crear aplicaciones de qt sin qt creator](https://www.linux.org/threads/c-tutorial-create-qt-applications-without-qtcreator.18409/) 2. [Enlazando qt con g++](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/linking-to-qt-with-g-4175707961/) 3. [Error al compilar aplicación de qt en ubuntu directamente con g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972933/error-compiling-qt-application-directly-with-g-on-ubuntu) 4. [Compilando qt con g++ (Qt Forum)](https://forum.qt.io/topic/129796/compiling-in-g)